# Trim HTML tags of a table cell with radio button and label combined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Javascript Function:

The function of my JS posted below is to loop through the column indexes defined in the 2nd parameter and at the same time loop also at the given element ids defined in the 3rd parameter. This will populated the textbox, radiobutton and dropdown fields based on the value of columns of the clicked row.

From the sample usage below, the value from column index 1 (price) will be shown in the price textbox when the table is clicked.

Sample Usage:

```
<table id="tblPrice" onclick="gettabledata('tblPrice', '0,1,2,3', 'PriceId,Price,strtDt,endDt')">
```

Problem:

The table's 2nd column (1st column is hidden) has a combination of radio button and label, and when the row is clicked the Price textbox has a value like this:

`<input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice" class="radio" value="">                <label style="font-size: 1em" class="price" for="lblPriceRbtn">5</label>`

I just need the value `5` to be shown in the Price textbox, so I need to trime the element tags being shown. All other cells with text only (no radiobutton) is copied correctly to their corresponding textboxes except for the cell that has a combination of radiobutton and label. The code responsible for this is:

`document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].innerHTML.trim();`

The `innerHTML.trim()` only removes the whitespaces when I get the cell value.

JavaScript (Go to line with comment: `Problem` to see the code with issue):

```
function gettabledata(tableId, colIndexes, fieldIds) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableId); //Get table id to evaluate
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'); //Get all table cells per column

    //Get field Ids set in parameter
    var fieldId = fieldIds.split(","); 
    var colIndex = colIndexes.split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];

        //Get column data on clicked row
        cell.onclick = function () {
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId]; //Get selected row

            //Get number of items in array and loop (NOTE: colIndex is an array parameter defined in called javascript from View)
            for (i = 0; i < fieldId.length; i++) {

                var elmntTag = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).tagName; //Get element tag name of each filedId item (SELECT, INPUT)
                var elmntType = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).getAttribute("type"); //Get element type of each filedId item (text, radio)

                //Check field if dropdown or input (text or radio)
                if (elmntTag == "INPUT") {

                    //Populate field depending on input type
                    if (elmntType == "text" || elmntType == "hidden") {

                        //PROBLEM
                        document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].innerHTML.trim(); //Populate value of textbox id defined in the parameter
                    } else if (elmntType == "radio") {

                        //Populate value of radiobutton id defined in the parameter
                        var status = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].innerHTML.trim();
                        var name = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).getAttribute("name");

                        if (status == "Active") {
                            $('input[name=' + name + '][value="Active"]').prop('checked', true);
                        } else if (status == "Inactive") {
                            $('input[name=' + name + '][value="Inactive"]').prop('checked', true);
                        }
                    }
                //Check field if dropdown or input (text or radio)
                } else if (elmntTag == "SELECT") {
                    var dropdown = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]);
                    dropdown.value = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].innerHTML.trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $('#btnUpdate').show();
    $('#btnSave').hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="template" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rbDefaultPrice" class="radio" />
            <label style="font-size: 1em" class="price"></label>
        </td>
        <td class="startdate"></td>
        <td class="enddate"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking several forums, I've come up with an answer:

I replaced my code from this:

`document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].innerHTML.trim();`

To this:

`document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[colIndex[i]].textContent.trim();`